# Exploiting orthogonality when integrating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-request

I have an orthogonal function in the integral. My job is to evaluate it and use the result for next step.
 To give you an idea, let me have an example,

```
ω := 100; (* =(2*π)/T *)
J1[j1_, t_] := j1 Cos[ω t]^2; 
J2[j2_, t_] := j2 Cos[ω t];;
int[j1_,j2_] = 
            (1/T)Integrate[
              Exp[-I*m*ω*t]*Sqrt[J1[j1, t]^2 + J2[j1, t]^2 + 
                 2 J1[j1, t] J2[j1, t] Cos[ka]]*Exp[I*n*ω*t], 
                                                  {t, 0, T}]
```

Usually Mathematica doesn't give results in that format, but I am not pasting the result as the format contains `Subscript` and other words and a huge expressions (which looked good in Mathematica but not when copied into Mathematica.SE). Anyway,here is the result of Mathematica(for the above code)
[image]

To make my query more clear, I am expecting the result as(an example)

```
intexpect[j1_, n_, m_] := (1/T)Integrate[
                      Exp[-I*m*ω*t]*J1[j1, t]*Exp[I*n*ω*t], 
                                                {t, 0, T}];
intexpect[j1_, n_, m_] := (j1/4)*δ(n,m+2)+(j1/4)*δ(n,m-2)
```

where δ is Kronecker Delta.

Is there a way in Mathematica to evaluate it in the Kronecker Delta (even for some fixed $n$ and $m$ in the above code) format. By making use of the orthogonality property of exponentials (by properly defining the integral in Mathematica, to give such results)? Or am I missing some essential point?

$$ (e_n, e_m) = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T e^{2\pi int}e^{-2\pi imt}dt = \delta_{n,m}$$

Otherwise, I have to calculate the integral by hand and then write the results of the surviving terms in Mathematica. This is cumbersome because I need to carry it out for many different cases and then write a new Mathematica file for each case.

After I tried it from my side(but for fix value of $n$ and $m$)

```
ClearAll;
T := 1;
\[Omega] := 2 \[Pi]/T;
J1[j1_, t_] := j1 Cos[\[Omega] t]^2;
J2[j2_, t_] := j2;
intexp[j1_, n_, m_] := 
  Module[{n1 = n, m1 = m}, 
   (1/T)Integrate[
    Exp[-I*m1*\[Omega]*t]*J1[j1, t]*Exp[I*n1*\[Omega]*t], {t, 0, 
     T}]];
intexp[j1, 1, 1]
Out[99]= j1/2
```

I can see from the functions in integrand and using [Fourier transform](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html) (is that is the only way to solve and get the surviving terms?)

As I am still new to Mathematica, please forgive me for any obvious or unrelated questions.

**Addendum**:
(i) When I am using NIntegrate in my just above code(where I tried from side, it is giving error). For later purpose, I need Numerical evaluation of the integral.
There are bunch of errors(three of them):

```
NIntegrate::izero :  Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.
NIntegrate::inumr :  The integrand E^(6 I \[Pi] t) (-E^(I k) j2-j1 Cos[\[Pi] t]^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,2}}.
NIntegrate::inumr :  The integrand E^(4 I \[Pi] t) (-E^(-I k) j2-j1 Cos[\[Pi] t]^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,2}}.
```

(ii) When I writing $n=1, m=3$, unexpected result is coming.

```
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -0.195312  \text{j1} \\
 -0.195312  \text{j1} & 0 \\
\end{array}
```

Instead of j1/4 on either side

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Its very difficult to understand what you want to achieve. `Integrate` is symbolic integration. Do you need a symbolic solution? In part "Mathematica don't give result...", you mention some expression. What did you mean by that? If some error is thrown, add it to the question. Do not worry about `Subscript`, because we can paste the expression in Mathematica for proper formatting.

Comment: @ercegovac Please see the edit

Comment: You might be able to use `FourierSeries` for this particular class of example.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can you enlighten a little bit?

Comment: With difficulty. The question is carelessly worded. I doubt an omega belongs, the `J1` might or might not correspond to `BesselJ`, the `T` probably needs to be a multiple of `2*Pi`, etc. What I had in mind can be seen from the two results below. `In[1662]:= 
intexpect1[j1_, n_Integer, m_Integer] := 
 1/(2*Pi) Integrate[Exp[-I*(m - n)*t]*BesselJ[j1, t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
intexpect1[3, 4, 3]
FourierCoefficient[BesselJ[3, t], t, -1]

Out[1663]= (I (\[Pi] BesselJ[0, \[Pi]] + 4 BesselJ[1, \[Pi]]))/\[Pi]

Out[1664]= (I (\[Pi] BesselJ[0, \[Pi]] + 4 BesselJ[1, \[Pi]]))/\[Pi]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Many many thanks to you. But J1 is just a function, please have a look at my program here: [With your helpful inputs](http://imgur.com/aQZX8tv). _Any input will be very very valuable_.

Comment: @Shamina I myself have not read it yet and I do not know if it applied to this case but concerning the difficulty in displaying the expressions in your code in a nice format you might be interested in this [post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/86543).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I come up with my answer, mainly help from MMSE and self. It works sufficiently fast and it avoids such nasty integrals. These integrals become pain in the neck, to show I used `J1[j2_, t_] := j1 Cos[ω t];` if the function grows like this `J1[j2_, t_] := j1 Cos[ω t]^8;`. This approach starts to cry and take a long time.
But using `Fourier Transform` in Mathematica, one can avoid such nasty integrations,
This is what was my problem

```
J1[j2_, t_] := j1 Cos[ω t];

intexp[j1_, n_, m_] := 
  Module[{n1 = n, m1 = m}, 
   (1/T)Integrate[
    Exp[-I*m1*ω*t]*J1[j1, t]*Exp[I*n1*ω*t], {t, 0, 
     T}]];
```

Changing to `FourierTransform`: Only difference is `Cos` without `ω` in this case.

```
ForInt[j1_, n_Integer, m_Integer] = 
  FourierTransform[M1[j1, t], t, n, 
    FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] /. 
   DiracDelta[x_] :> KroneckerDelta[x, m];
```

To test the efficiency:

```
In[1]:= 
T = 1/10; (*Time Period of the external driving field*)
ω = (2*\
\[Pi])/T;
M1[j1_, t_] := j1 Cos[ t]^4
J1[j1_, t_] := j1 Cos[ ω t]^4
ForInt[n_Integer, m_Integer, k_] = 
  FourierTransform[M1[j1, t], t, n, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] /. 
   DiracDelta[x_] :> KroneckerDelta[x, m];
First@AbsoluteTiming[ForInt[1, 3, k]]
intexp[j1_, n_, m_] := 
  Module[{n1 = n, 
    m1 = m}, (1/T) Integrate[
     Exp[-I*m1*ω*t]*J1[j1, t]*Exp[I*n1*ω*t], {t, 0, T}]];
First@AbsoluteTiming[intexp[1, 3, k]]

Out[6]= 0.000012

Out[8]= 3.21761
```

Which is around $5$ orders of difference.